# How to query all child objects of a list for matching entities?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm a bit of a neophyte when it comes to LINQ and lambda expressions, I'm hoping someone can help me out.

What I'm doing is creating an aggregate object from an ADO.NET SqlDataReader with multiple data 'tables' in the response.

The recordsets look like this:

**Foo**
FooId  
...other descriptive fields

**Bar**
BarId 
FooId 
...other descriptive fields

**Baz**
BazId 
BarId 
...other descriptive fields

I'm iterating through each data table, one at a time.  After I've processed the first table, I have all my "Foos", then the second one is the "Bars", which I can associate to the "Foo" without any trouble.  (a "Bar" can be assigned to more than one Foo).

The object I'm hydrating is a List (for purposes of returning it via a web service) and the objects look like this (pseudocode):

```
class Foo
{
  int FooId
  string Name
  string etc
  string YouGetTheIdea
  List<Bar> Bars
}

class Bar
{
  int BarId
  string etc
  List<Baz> Bazes
}

class Baz
{
  int BazId
  string etc
}
```

Up to this point, I'm fine.  Where I get into trouble is that the "Bar" objects have a list of "Baz" objects which can be attached to more than one "Bar" (which in turn can be attached to more than one "Foo")

My code, thus far, looks something like this.  If there's a better way to approach this, please let me know.  **My trouble is that when I get to the section dealing with "Baz," I'm not sure how to select all "Bar" objects (under any Foo who has a Bar with that Id) so I can add the current BazId to its list of Baz objects.**  What I have in here currently is blowing up at runtime, so it's obviously not right.

```
using (SafeDataReader reader = this.ExecSPReader(SP_NAME, parms.ToArray()))
{
    if (reader != null)
    {
        // deal with Foos
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Foo o = new Foo();
            o.FooID = reader.GetInt64("FooID");
            o.Etc = reader.GetString("etc");
            //...more properties
            fooList.Add(o);
        }

        // deal with Bars
        reader.NextResult();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Bar p = new Bar();
            long BarFooID = reader.GetInt64("FooID");

            p.BarID = reader.GetInt64("BarID");
            //...more properties

            // find Foo that has this Bar and add to it
            Foo o = fooList.Find(x => x.FooID == barFooID);
            if (o != null)
            {
                if (o.Bars == null)
                {
                    o.Bars = new List<Bar>();
                }
                o.Bars.Add(p);
            }
        }
/*
***
***  Up to here, everything is fine
***  ...but now we need to assign the baz elements to bars, which can belong 
***     to any/all Foos
***
*/
        // deal with Bazs
        reader.NextResult();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            long bazID = reader.GetInt64("BazID");
            long barID = reader.GetInt64("BarID");

            // here is the problem, ideally I'd like to get a list of all Bar elements with
            // the BarID from the datarow, but not sure how to do that -- the below foreach
            // line errors at runtime
            foreach(Bar p in fooList.Select(a => a.Bars.Where(b => b.BarID == barID)))
            {
                if (p.Bazes == null)
                {
                    p.Bazes = new List<Baz>();
                }
                p.Bazes.Add(bazID);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: _which can be attached to more than one "Bar"_ - not with the given Table definitons. Make sure you are clear about 1-to-N and N-to-M relations and then give up and use Entity Framework.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Why can't it be attached to more than one Bar?

Comment: @HenkHolterman -- those aren't tables, they're a query output.  You're correct if it was the table def, that would be a 1-1 relationship, but there are multiple rows for a given BazId.  :)

Comment: Not 1-1 but 1-N. Pay attention to those cardinalities, they are important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SelectMany (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
foreach(Bar p in fooList.SelectMany(a => a.Bars.Where(b => b.BarID == barID)))
            {
                if (p.Bazes == null)
                {
                    p.Bazes = new List<Baz>();
                }
                p.Bazes.Add(bazID);
            }
```

*Update as a.Bars could potentially be null;*

```
foreach(Bar p in fooList.Where(a => a.Bars !=null).SelectMany(a => a.Bars.Where(b => b.BarID == barID)))
            {
                if (p.Bazes == null)
                {
                    p.Bazes = new List<Baz>();
                }
                p.Bazes.Add(bazID);
            }
```

Comment: Bob -- this is perfect and appears to do exactly what I'm wanting.  Can't believe I was so close!  Thanks also for the update about the null check.  I put that in as well.